# Can we access gsutil from Google Cloud Dataflow? if yes, then could someone please explain with example?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, gsutil

I'm new with google cloud dataflow and I need to copy files in GCS (Google Cloud Storage) from one bucket to another and rename. Answer with example would highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes you can do this, but it would be better if you used Dataflow to just pick up the files and move them over to the new bucket instead of as a wrapper around gustil.

The class you need should be beam.io.gcsio.GcsIO() and that should be able to pick up and put down files where you need it too.

Comment: can this be used to download to local worker, not just move between buckets? I tried google-cloud-storage python module and it doesn't work well compared to gsutil for large (3gb) objects.

Comment: Yes it can, that method call will load the object that is passed to it off of storage and into the local instance of the executing dataflow worker.

My recommendation for larger objects, lets say >20MB , would be to carve that thing into workable bundles, and to serialize that object across as you will get better performance that way. This is assuming that the object that you are dealing with can be decomposed.

Comment: Yup, working on chunking, though its a bit circular. To make the chunks one must download the file, then reupload and run dataflow on the chunks. Can you give one line of example code about the syntax of local download, all I see is the slightly terse: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.html